# How do I include non-.py files in PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, manifest, setup.py, pypi

I am a newb to PyPI...so let me qualify with that. I am trying to put a package on PyPI but having a bit of trouble when I try to install it with pip. When I upload the file to PyPI, I get a warning (but the setup.py script finishes with not fatal errors and a 200 status):

```
'my_package/static/my_folder' not a regular file -- skipping
```

And then when I go to install it in pip, I get an error:

```
"error: can't copy 'my_package/static/my_folder': doesn't exist or not a regular file.
```

From other answers on SO, I've tried changing up my MANIFEST.in and my setup.py files, with no luck. Here is my current MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-include my_package *.css *.js *.jinja2
```

and setup.py:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_package',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    platforms='any',
    version='1.0',
    description='my_description',
    license='MIT',
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@example.com',
    install_requires=[
        'Flask',
        'Jinja2',
        'requests',
    ],
    url='http://www.example.com',
    download_url='https://github.com/me/my_package/tarball/1.0',
    classifiers=[
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    ],
)
```

EDIT: I've also tried leaving out the MANIFEST.in file just to see if that was messing anything up but I get the same result.

Comment: Just built a simple project with two files (`my_package/__init__.py` and `my_package/static/a.css`), and your `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in` works fine. Do you have additional rules in your manifest? Would be nice if you could provide a minimal project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @uranusjr: That worked. I then deleted the entire package on PyPI and resubmitted with no issues. Must have been something on PyPI's end. Since you effectively resolved the issue please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Reposted from the comment on request.)

Your setup script and `MANIFEST.in` should work. To prove this with a minimal example:

```
my_project/
    my_package/
        static/
            a.css
        __init__.py
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
```

Run `python setup.py sdist` and you'll find that both `static/a.css` and `__init__.py` are bundled in the `tar.gz` package.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you’re asking for. The answer already includes a `__init__.py`, and you should not need to do anything to the manifest since setuptools automatically include all `__init__.py` contained in directories specifies in `packages`.