# How to access pickle data in python package

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I am attempting to publish a package on PyPI (as a newbie) which contains data stored as a pickle file. But I don't seem to be able to read the data in my main code.

My package structure is:

```py
package/
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.in
    package/
        package.py
        __init__.py
        data.pkl
```

And my code in package.py is somewhat like this:

```py
data = pickle.load(open('data.pkl', 'rb'))

def doSomething(data):
    ***code to do something on data***
    return variable

var = doSomething(data)
```

When I install the package and try to import it, I get the error:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.pkl'
```

It appears my `package.py` can't find my pickle file. Yes, I set `include_package_data = True` in `setup.py` and the the pickle file is loaded via the `MANIFEST.in` file.

I have tried loading the pickle file in `__init__.py` or specifying the full path (`package/data.pkl`), but none of these work.

Comment: Have you tried a relative path like "./data.pkl"?

Comment: Is the pickle in the package? (Every package is just a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` archive that you can list). Is it installed after the package installation?

Comment: Specifying a relative path (./data.pkl) yields the same error.  The pickle is in the package after installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of data.pkl relative to the source code must be specified. And this can be done using the `__file__` variable (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559186/filenotfounderror-errno-2-when-packaging-for-pypi)).

The following code solved it for me

```py
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)  # Get path of data.pkl
data_path = os.path.join(this_dir, 'data.pkl')
data = pickle.load(open(data_path, 'rb'))
```