# Relative paths within a pip package

Tags: python, import, pip, relative-path

I am writing my first pip package, but I have trouble with relative paths. The package structure is as follows:

```
.
├── packname
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── packfile1.py
│   ├── packfile2.py
│   └── packfile3.py
│
├── datatoload
│   ├── toload1.pkl
│   ├── toload2.pkl
│   ├── toload3.pkl
│   └── toload4.pkl
│
└── requirements.txt
```

Some python files in the `packname` directory need to load data from files in the datatoload directory. I have some questions about managing package files and data.

Is it ok to have a separate folder for the data to load?

Since I want people to use my package, should I add some properties to my package (I read something about `__file__` and `__path__`)?

Moreover, do you have any more advice about this?

Thank you :)

**UPDATE**
A user in the comments told me that the folder needs to be inside the package folder, as follows:

```
.
├── packname
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── packfile1.py
│   ├── packfile2.py
│   │── packfile3.py
│   │
│   └─ datatoload
│      ├── toload1.pkl
│      ├── toload2.pkl
│      ├── toload3.pkl
│      └── toload4.pkl
│
└── requirements.txt
```

The most important question I want to ask is: how do I setup the relative path to be used inside the package? For example, if I want to load data saved in `toload2.pkl` from a function in `packfile3.py`, can I simply do

```
load('./datatoload/toload2.pkl')
```

Would this work when someone downloads my package (together with the `datatoload` folder)?

Comment: "*Is it ok to have a separate folder for the data to load?*" No, it must be inside the package to avoid polluting installation directory. "*…\__file__ and \__path__…*" No need, Python adds these variable automatically on import.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Reading your question I notice that I missed a crucial question about HOW to import with a relative path in a python package. I will update the question :)

Comment: "*`load('./datatoload/toload2.pkl')` Would this work when someone downloads my package…?*? No because `./` means the current directory and the current directory for user could be anything. You need to calculate you package directory using `os.path.dirname(__file__)`; like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843242/7976758

Comment: Thank you again @phd! Would you like to post your comments as an answer? I'd be glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to have a separate folder for the data to load?

No, it must be inside the package to avoid polluting installation directory.

> …__file__ and __path__…

No need, Python [adds these variables](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#path__) automatically on import.

> `load('./datatoload/toload2.pkl')` Would this work when someone downloads my package…?

No because `./` means the current directory and the current directory for user could be anything. You need to calculate you package directory using `os.path.dirname(__file__)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843242/7976758/ for an example.